# Where's the best place to ask about math algorithm? Here or Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

If I have a question about a mathematical computation algorithm that could be implemented as a computer program but my question is primarily about the math involved, for example how to correctly apply the algorithm in base 65536 instead of base 10, is such a question appropriate on Math Stack Exchange? I'm asking because some questions are tagged [algoritms].

Comment: We often answer questions about algorithms and about specific computations. I don't know what the best place is, but I from what little you have said about the question, I think it would be reasonable to ask it here.

Comment: I have ventured onto SO a few times, and have been disappointed by what I perceive to be a much less helpful and friendly culture. Moreover SO gets an order of magnitude more questions per day and yours is more likely to get lost in the shuffle -- for these reasons I would ask here instead whenever possible.